# Delphi SOAP empty array (mapping to objects)

Tags: xml, delphi, soap

I imported WSDL file in Delphi XE7 and there is a problem with TTypeTranslator.CastSoapToVariant function with dynamic arrays (System.TTypeKind.tkDynArray).

In SOAP envelopes there are positions like
...
and they are parsed right but some of them are

and then TTypeTranslator.CastSoapToVariant raises an exception which causes the whole invokaction to fail.

Is there a way to manage those  elements as they are parsed to objects?

Comment: What exception is raised? Can you give MCVE code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ETypeTransException: Type cannot be cast as Variant. The code is just invocation of SOAP method like that: result := serv.GetData(params)

Comment: Please post the wsdl so we can reproduce?

Comment: The WSDL file is here: http://www.filedropper.com/transactionsoapservice Please help :) Maybe there is another way to import it to Delphi. Otherwise I can see only one solution - parsing SOAP Envelope by myself.

Comment: Any idea? maybe somebody has similiar problems...